# Using attr in layout , LayoutInflater.inflater(layout,null)

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to use `attr` in 2 dialog themes.
I've created a dialog:

```
LayoutInflater.inflater(layout,null);
```

but got the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13
```

I could not change activity theme.
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <attr name="mainBackground" format="color" />
</resources>


<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="gl_black" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="mainBackground">@color/main_background</item>
</style>
<style name="gl_white" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="mainBackground">@color/gl_color_white</item>
</style>
<style name="gl_dialog_login" parent="@style/gl_black">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater.from(context)
```

change context.

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(context,style);
```